# Identificar el numero mayor

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio con arreglos sobre una tienda de abarrotes y hay un requisito el cual no me da la cabeza para resolverlo, básicamente el programa consiste en esto:

Dado un número “n” de clientes, solicita por cada uno de los clientes los datos siguientes:

- Nombre
- El monto total de la compra

A todos los clientes por el Buen Fin se les otorga un 20% de descuento en el total de la compra, por lo que deberá calcular el total a pagar con el descuento incluido por cada cliente y escribir un listado en el que se muestre por cada uno lo siguiente:

- Nombre
- Total a pagar con descuento por cada cliente

Además, se deberá mostrar en dicho listado:

- El total a pagar con descuento por todo los clientes
- El cliente que pagó la mayor cantidad y el monto pagado.

Y este es el código que he realizado para el problema:

```
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Dado un numero n, se establece el total de clientes que tuvo la tienda de abarrotes
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es la cantidad total de clientes?"); 
    int clientes= leer.nextInt();
    
    //Estas son las variables de nombre y compra respectivamente con el uso de arreglos
    String[] nom= new String [clientes];
    double compra[]= new double [clientes];
    
    //Con el uso del ciclo for se lee el nombre y el total de compra de cada cliente con los arreglos previamente definidos
    for (int i=0; i<clientes; i++){
        System.out.println("Escriba su nombre para esta compra");
        nom[i]= leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Indique también cual es su monto total de compra");
        compra[i] = leer.nextDouble();
        
        //Calculo para el total con descuento del 20%
        double total=compra[i]*0.80;
        //Impresion de todos los datos establecidos (por cada cliente)
        System.out.println("!Este buen fin recibe un 20% de descuento en sus compras¡");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Nombre asignado a su compra:"+nom[i]);
        System.out.println("Monto total a pagar:"+compra[i]);
        System.out.println("Total a pagar con descuento (promocion de buen fin):"+total);
        
        //Este metodo if se encarga de sumar todas las compras (con descuento) de cada uno de los clientes
        //para después, imprimirlos como se ve abajo
        if (i==clientes){
            double todos=total++;
            System.out.println("El total con descuento de cada cliente fue de "+todos);
        }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien pero mi problema surge cuando necesito hacer el ultimo punto que me pide la actividad el cual es el de imprimir al cliente que pagó la mayor cantidad y el monto pagado de dicho cliente, espero que me puedan ayudar con esta ultima parte, ¿Cómo puedo enseñarle al programa a identificar cual es el mayor para que lo pueda imprimir? de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes considerar que i inicia en 0 por ende nunca sera igual a cliente,lo otro es que deberias crear un arreglo extra para los precios con descuento,esto me parece un programilla mas para POO pero esta bien estructurado, para conseguir el mayor necesitas una variable auxiliar que compare todos los valores del nuevo arreglo y capture el mayor de ellos ,de paso capturas en otra variable el nombre del cliente que pago mas ,te adjunto tu codigo modificado

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    

Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Dado un numero n, se establece el total de clientes que tuvo la tienda de abarrotes
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es la cantidad total de clientes?"); 
    int clientes= leer.nextInt();
    
    //Estas son las variables de nombre y compra respectivamente con el uso de arreglos
    String[] nom= new String [clientes];
    double compra[]= new double [clientes];
    double precioConDescuento[]=new double [clientes];
    double todos=0;
    double mayor=0;
    String cliente =null;
    
    //Con el uso del ciclo for se lee el nombre y el total de compra de cada cliente con los arreglos previamente definidos
    for (int i=0; i<clientes; i++){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Escriba su nombre para esta compra");
        nom[i]= leer.next();
        System.out.println("Indique también cual es su monto total de compra");
        compra[i] = leer.nextDouble();
        
        //Calculo para el total con descuento del 20%
        double total=compra[i]*0.80;
        precioConDescuento[i]=total;
        //Impresion de todos los datos establecidos (por cada cliente)
        System.out.println("!Este buen fin recibe un 20% de descuento en sus compras¡");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Nombre asignado a su compra:"+nom[i]);
        System.out.println("Monto total a pagar:"+compra[i]);
        System.out.println("Total a pagar con descuento (promocion de buen fin):"+total);
        
        //Este metodo if se encarga de sumar todas las compras (con descuento) de cada uno de los clientes
        //para después, imprimirlos como se ve abajo
        
        todos+=total;

         } 

         for(int i=0;i<clientes;i++){
               if(precioConDescuento[i]>mayor){
                    mayor=precioConDescuento[i];
                    cliente=nom[i];
               }
         }  
            System.out.println("\nEl total con descuento de cada cliente fue de "+String.format("%.2f",todos));
            System.out.println("EL cliente que pago mas fue :"+ cliente+ " lo que pago fue "+String.format("%.2f",mayor));

        
    
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sería comparar los valores con e ir guardando el mayor en una variable mayor previamente declarada. Al final de la iteracción se muestra el contenido de esta variable mayor.
El fragmento, (usando las variables de tu código) sería el siguiente:

```
double num_mayor=0;

    // se recorren los demás elementos buscan si hay alguno mayor que num_mayor
    for (int i=0; i<clientes; i++){
        if (precioConDescuento[i]>num_mayor) { // si hay un valor mayor que num_mayor
            num_mayor=precioConDescuento[i]; // el nuevo dato toma el primer puesto (mayor de todos)
        }
}

System.out.println("EL cliente que pago mas fue :"+ cliente+ " lo que pago fue "+String.format("%.2f",num_mayor));
```